# Can you recast an enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have created an interface `Columns` which is extended by a number of enums of the pattern `ColumnsReportname`. One of the methods defined in the interface is `getHeaderText()`.

I have also created a method `createHeader(Columns[])` which *ideally* creates a header row based on `ColumnsReportname.values()`.

Except it doesn't work because `createHeader(Columns[])` won't accept `ColumnsReportname` parameters.

So I *can* just create a List of header names and pass those in, but do I need to or is there an easier way?

method:

```
public void setHeader(Columns[] columns) {
    List<Object> headers = new Vector<Object>();
    for (Columns c : columns) {
        headers.add(c.getHeaderText());
    }
    headerRow = new Row(headers, true);
}
```

enum:

```
public enum ColumnsObligations implements Columns {
CLAIMNO(15, "Claim #", false), ACTIONDATE(10, "Action Dt.", false), DATEPAID(10, "Dt. Paid", false), ACTION(15, "Action"), CLAIMANT(
        15, "Claimant"), FY(6, "FY", false), FUNDCITE(15, "Fund Cite"), AMTPAID(15, "Amt Paid", true), CHECKNO(15, "Ins. Dpt."), VOUCHERNO(
        15, "Voucher No.");

private ColumnsObligations(int colWidth, String headerText, boolean totaled) {
    this.colWidth = colWidth;
    this.headerText = headerText;
    this.totaled = totaled;
}

private ColumnsObligations(int colWidth, String headerText) {
    this.colWidth = colWidth;
    this.headerText = headerText;
    this.totaled = false;
}

private final int colWidth;
private final String headerText;
private final boolean totaled;

public int getColWidth() {
    return colWidth;
}

public String getHeaderText() {
    return headerText;
}

public boolean isTotaled() {
    return this.totaled;
}
```

Thank you.

Edit: Solution

```
public <T extends Columns> void setHeader(T... columns) {
    List<Object> headers = new Vector<Object>();
    for (Columns c : columns) {
        headers.add(c.getHeaderText());
    }
    headerRow = new Row(headers, true);
}
```

Comment: Are you passing `ColumnsReportname` to `Columns[]` or `ColumsnReportname[]`? It would be better if you show us some code.

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: Example has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createHeader(Columns[])` doesn't accept `ColumnsReportname` parameters, because a `Columnsreportname` parameter is not *an array of Columns instances*.

You can change a bit the signature of the `createHeader` method and make it generic:

```
public <T extends Columns> void createHeader(T ... params)
```

This will allow you to pass an optional number of `Columns` subclasses (like `ColumnsReportname`).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I need to brush up on my generics it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `List` of header names.

If you are trying to use a collection in conjunction with subtyping, arrays can get you into trouble. See Josh Bloch's *Effective Java: 2nd Edition*, Item 25, ("Prefer lists to arrays") and this example from it:

```
// Fails at runtime!
Object[] objectArray = new Long[1];
objectArray[0] = "I don't fit in"; // Throws ArrayStoreException
```

Versus this:

```
// Won't compile!
List<Object> ol = new ArrayList<Long>(); // Incompatible types 
ol.add("I don't fit in");
```